# Resize SVG in CSS past 100%

Tags: html, css, svg, scaling, styling

Is there any way to resize an SVG in css that goes beyond the 100% of the original image? I currently have the svg in a `img` tag and have removed the height and width from the SVG file. Currently I have tried to set the height and width in css but it won't scale up beyond 100%. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, seems like this is somehow linked to the `viewbox` that is set in the svg.

```
<img class="map" src="map.svg" alt="Map">
```

```
.map{
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have stumbled back upon something I tried earlier and this time it worked! If you move the class up a level to a wrapper then width should work as expected.

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="map.svg" alt="Map">
</div>
```

```
.map{
  width: 100vw;
}
```